# In Android Room Can I loop through all Records

Tags: java, android, sqlite, loops, android-room

Hi Guys so I checked the Android tutorial for Room Sqlite which is nice but I am facing a small problem.

I created a table with two columns Keys and Values (both strings).

```
@Entity(tableName = "key_table")
public class Key {
@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
private int id;
private String key;
private String value;
//...Setters and getters and contructor
```

With regards to the [Google docs](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room) I made several files : The Entity (class), The Dao, The Database, The Repository, The ViewModel the adapter (recycler) for listview . I was Happy to see everything working with an Activity/ Fragment.

**Now The Problem : Is it possible to do something simple like Get all the rows KEYS & VALUES and loop through them??**

Now In the Dao File I have:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM key_table ORDER BY id DESC")
LiveData<List<Key>> getAllkeys();
```

I tried to think of a way to loop through this LiveData List but the only thing that I found was setting an observer and waiting for a change and setting adapter clas for ListView.

I tried adding something like this in the KeyDao.java file:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM key_table ORDER BY id DESC")
List<Key> getKeys();
```

also I have KeyRepository.java where I added some code to call the getKeys(); that I added in the Dao

```
public class KeyRepository {
    private KeyDao keyDao;
    private LiveData<List<Key>> allKeys;
    private List<Key> TheKeys;
    public KeyRepository(Application application) {
      KeyDatabase database = KeyDatabase.getInstance(application);
      keyDao = database.keyDao();
      allKeys = keyDao.getAllkeys();
      TheKeys = keyDao.getKeys();
    }

    public void insert(Key key) {
      new InsertKeyAsyncTask(keyDao).execute(key);
    }

    public void update(Key key) {
      new UpdateKeyAsyncTask(keyDao).execute(key);
    }

    public void delete(Key key) {
      new DeleteKeyAsyncTask(keyDao).execute(key);
    }

    public void deleteAllKeys() {
      new DeleteAllKeysAsyncTask(keyDao).execute();
    }

    public LiveData<List<Key>> getAllKeys() {
      return allKeys;
    }
    //I ADDED THIS
    public List<Key>  getKeys() {
      return TheKeys;
    }
// The implementation of the Asyncs ...
```

Ok So far I got an Error and Managed to make it work by Adding the .allowMainThreadQueries () in the DataBuilder following @Christilyn suggestion.

Still the result is an Empty Array!! I am missing something ?
with the changes to the Keyrepository.java file where I tried to add the getKeys() but I got an error, I was thinking of doing something like this on the activity or fragment :

```
keyViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(KeyViewModel.class);
List<Key>  keys = keyViewModel.getKeys();
int s = keys.size();
for(int i=0;i<s; i++){
  Key k;
  k = keys.get(i);
  //... Now we should loop but the getKeys(); doesnt work !! maybe it's a wrong approach
}
```

**So can we just loop through that LiveData which is suposed to encapsulate data without setting up an observer and waiting for a change?**

Comment: By default, room does not allow you to execute queries on the main thread. So you have to do it asynchronously and get the data from there. If you really need to, you can add `allowMainThreadQueries ()` method in your `RoomDatabase.Builder`

Comment: Hey @ Christilyn Thanks for your reply, in my KeyRepository class I have a couple of function cloned from android tutorial and the update,insert,delete extend AsyncTask but the getall is declared without async, can I make work I mean Stripping LiveData in the Dao?

Comment: Have you tried `Room.databaseBuilder(...).allowMainThreadQueries().build()` ?

Comment: @ Christilyn Ok so far the exeption that I got from the repository java file is gone and it compiles but I get an Array of size 0 . I think I might be on something. Also I will some code from KeyRepository.java in my question. Still not solved

Comment: @ Christilyn I managed to make it work using asyncs as suggested but strangely it still requires allowMainThreadQueries() Thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning values to your `allKeys` variable incorrectly within your constructor. With `LiveData` you need to setup observer as below.

```
keyDao.getAllkeys().observe(this, new Observer<List<Key>>() {
    @Override
    public void onChanged(@Nullable List<Key> keysFromDB) {
        allKeys = keysFromDB;
    }
});
```

Comment: Man I feel so stupid after reading your code lol. So If I put it in my constructor and I add a allKeys  private variable it will do the initialisation, But I need to try it up

Comment: Test this and accept the answer if it works. Good luck

Comment: Ok It does work However The onChange is kinda executing in Async so all related stuff must be inside that onchanged event